# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

"Согласно внесенным изменениям(,) в случае неудачной сдачи теста(,) претендент может сразу пройти повторное тестирование".

Answer (score 2):

Оборот с предлогом *в случае* не нужно выделять запятыми. Оборот с предлогом *согласно* обособляется факультативно, решение за автором текста. В данном конкретном случае я посоветовал бы отделить его запятой от последующего оборота, чтобы облегчить понимание. Таким образом, общая пунктуация такова: *Согласно внесенным изменениям, в случае неудачной сдачи теста претендент может сразу пройти повторное тестирование.*

Answer (score 1):

Согласно внесенным изменениям, в случае неудачной сдачи теста претендент может сразу пройти повторное тестирование.