# Запятая после "согласно"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после слова "согласно" в предложениях типа: "Согласно правилам русского языка(,) "не" с глаголами пишется раздельно"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение короткое — можно не ставить запятую, тем более что “согласно” это предлог, после группы “предлог + относящиеся к нему слова” обычно запятые не ставят.

В более длинных иногда запятая после оборота с “согласно” допустима и даже нужна, чтобы легче было понимать фразу.

Answer (score 0):

См. мой ответ на сходный вопрос [тут.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, так как по правилу: Согласно правилам русского языка - это источник, на который указывает говорящий.
Например: По прогнозам синоптиков, в пятницу будет дождь. Запятая ставится,т.к. "По прогнозу синоптиков" – это источник

Comment: Ссылку на правило русского языка об источнике можете дать?

Comment: А источник подобного правила не назовете? Насчет источника?! 
Вообще весьма полный разбор подобных случае есть здесь:
http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/
Про источник - ни слова.
 

Comment: В каких-то справочниках было такое, что слова со значением источника являются вводными и отделяются запятыми. Например: "Как сказали синоптики, будет дождь". Конструкция "как сказали синоптики" вводная. 
"Согласно правилам" — неоднозначная ситуация.

Comment: >слова со значением источника являются вводными и отделяются запятыми  
  
Это только в оборотах с союзом как. Да и то формулировка оставляет желать... Кстати, тут еще с терминологией надо разбираться. Насколько понимаю, не всякие вводные слова - обособленный оборот.

Comment: Не только с *"как"*. Например, "по моему мнению" — тоже источник информации.      
Вводные слова не являются членами предложения, поэтому они не могут обособляться, они отделяются запятыми. Так, по крайней мере, когда-то учительница по русскому в школе говорила.

Comment: Обособляются и отделяются запятой - разве это не одно и тоже?